# Python create list of objects from list of 2 elements lists

Tags: python, list, object, setattr

I have a list of lists of 2-element lists, e.g.:

```
[[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]], [[g, h], [i, j], [k, l]]]
```

and I want to create a list of objects with attributes from the two-element lists, like this:

```
[(obj.a = b, obj.c=d, obj.e=f), (obj.g=h, obj.i=j, obj.k=l)]
```

I tried many ways, but seems I really don't know how, creating an object like `a = object()` and setting attrs via `object.__setattr__` didn't work for me.

Comment: What does *"didn't work for me"* mean, exactly? Where is your code, and what precisely is wrong with it? Does your list actually (eventually) contain strings, or some other objects?

Comment: Yes a big reason why this question is not answerable in its current form is that you did not follow the guideline of posting code that you're actually attempting to run

Comment: You're right, both of You, but let's say after 3 hours of rewriting from many angles, i'm not sure which try i should passt exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set arbitrary attributes on `object` instances:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> a.b = 'c'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
    a.b = 'c'
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Howver, you can create a `Generic` class that will allow you to:

```
class Generic(object):
    pass
```

Then, **assuming your list contains string pairs**:

```
l = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], 
     [['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l']]]
```

you can iterate over it as follows:

```
out = []
for ll in l:
    obj = Generic()
    for attr, val in ll:
        setattr(obj, attr, val)
    out.append(obj)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the three-argument form of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to create arbitrary classes, then create instances of those:

```
out = [type("Generic", (object,), dict(ll))() for ll in l]
```

Note that e.g.

```
>>> dict(l[0])
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

---

Finally, if you have an actual (not generic) object that takes e.g. `a`, `c`, `e` as arguments to `__init__`:

```
class Actual(object):
    def __init__(self, a, c, e):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c
        self.e = e
```

You can use dictionary unpacking to create an instance from the sub-list e.g. `l[0]`:

```
obj = Actual(**dict(l[0]))
```

Comment: This was exactly what i had in mind, after few hours i made "brutal" assigment (created object, by some inner cycles takeout data from "inside" of inner list and assigned it manualy), but that iteration about pairs is exactly what i needed. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use a dict:

```
>>> A=[[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]], [["g", "h"], ["i", "j"], ["k", "l"]]] 
>>> [x for x in A]
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], [['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l']]]
>>> B = [dict(x) for x in A]
>>> repr(B)
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}, {'i': 'j', 'k': 'l', 'g': 'h'}]
```

Comment: I'm not realy sure about mechanism you are using here, can you please clarify a little ? I was trying to make dict from inner list, but i always get error like : need #0 length of 2 but 5 is provided, which i'm unsure what it means when i always have pairs inside inner list (checked x times by pprint on every step)